# Purpose of the noaccess user in UNIX?

Tags: unix, solaris, passwd

Can someone point me to a document or explain to me the utility or application of the noaccess user? It would seem interchangeable with any other user I might create. What is it's purpose of being included by default in new installations of Solaris? (and presumably Linux)

Answer (score 2):

Running a task as a limited account is one way of adhering to the principle of least privilege. Having a standard limited account that various software packages can use for such a purpose makes things easier. Without it you may need to create and use an equivalent in some way.

An example would be the [Java Web Console](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/819-2379/frjpw/index.html) for Solaris 10 from Oracle which has a note:

> By default, the web console runs under the user identity, noaccess.
>   However, some system configurations disable the noaccess user, or set
>   the login shell for the noaccess user to an invalid entry to make this
>   user identity unusable.
>
> When the noaccess user is not usable, the web console server cannot be
>   started or configured, so an alternative user identity must be
>   specified. Ideally, the user identity should be changed only once,
>   before the console server is configured at initial startup.